# Show image with a background colour - CSS

Tags: css

I think all of you are familiar with this, images on facebook comes with a default background
How can i achieve same type of background color for images [without using any div just for the background]
As you can see my codes also creates background color but they are not rectangle in size :(

This is the preview

[image: My CSS vs FB CSS]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Your question's not very clear, but here's how to use a background colour and image on the same element:

`#element-id { background: #999 url(path/to/image.gif); }`

or, in longhand

`#element-id { background-color: #999; background-image: url(path/to/image.gif); }`

Comment: change `#element-id` to `img` or, if you wish to be specific, the `class` of the images you want to affect.

Comment: but they have a perfect rectangular back !